# Is it possible to write a custom EnumConverter that will be used instead of the default EnumConverter?

Tags: c#, enums

Is it possible to write a custom `EnumConverter` for an enum type that always will be used instead of the default `EnumConverter`?

I would like for this converter to be used everywhere in my XAML code without needing to specify what converter to use (if possible)

Answer (score 6):

I found how to do this :-) This will translate all the enums of this type into selected strings.

First I had to add a TypeConverter attribute to my enum:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfTestTypeConverter
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(DeviceTypeConverter))]
    public enum DeviceType
    {
        Computer,
        Car,
        Bike,
        Boat,
        TV
    }
}
```

And I also had to write a converter based on the EnumConverter class

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;

namespace WpfTestTypeConverter
{
    public class DeviceTypeConverter : EnumConverter
    {
        public DeviceTypeConverter(Type type) : base(type)
        {
        }

        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            return (destinationType == typeof(string));
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (value is DeviceType)
            {
                DeviceType x = (DeviceType)value;

                switch (x)
                {
                    case DeviceType.Computer:
                        return "This is a computer";
                    case DeviceType.Car:
                        return "A big car";
                    case DeviceType.Bike:
                        return "My red bike";
                    case DeviceType.Boat:
                        return "Boat is a goat";
                    case DeviceType.TV:
                        return "Television";
                    default:
                        throw new NotImplementedException("{x} is not translated. Add it!!!");
                }
            }
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }
    }
}
```

This works. Anyone have any comments about this solution?

Comment: You might want to use data annotations, then you can put description tags on the enums and use a function to pull the tag out rather than hard coding a switch statement.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I used nearly your exact code in my solution, to great effect.  Did you end up ever making improvements to it?